# Hover all child elements with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hey guys i have a div that contains an `image` and a `<figure>` with a `<figcaption>`. I want it so when someone mouses over the box it fires all of the hover effects. any ideas? here is how i do my hover effects.

the HTML:

```
    <a href="http://support.jonar.com/support/default.asp?W2294">
    <div class="box1">
        <figure>
            <img class="jlogo" src=
            "http://www.jonar.com/portal/partner/img/jonar_logo_white.png">
            <figcaption>
                Jonar &amp; You
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
</a>
```

THE CSS:

css effect for `box1` hover

```
 .box1:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(25, 16, 20), rgb(74, 41, 39));
    background: -o-linear-gradient(rgb(25, 16, 20), rgb(74, 41, 39));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(25, 16, 20), rgb(74, 41, 39));
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(25, 16, 20), rgb(74, 41, 39));
}
```

Jquery hover effect to change logo to colored logo

```
$(".jlogo").on({
 "mouseover" : function() {
    this.src = 'http://www.jonar.com/portal/partner/img/jonar_logo_color.png';
  },
  "mouseout" : function() {
    this.src='http://www.jonar.com/portal/partner/img/jonar_logo_white.png';
  }
});
```

I guess i want when someone mouses over the `box1` it fires even the logo change jquery.

Comment: Could be as simple as a div with a background image and do it with CSS and no JavaScript

Comment: What do you mean by "fire all the hover effects"? Do you want it to fire the hover effects of the `.jlogo` when you hover the `.box1`?

Comment: So listen for mouseenter on the box and find the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var $logo =  $(".jlogo");

$('.box1').on({
    'mouseover': function () {
       $logo.attr('src', 'http://www.jonar.com/portal/partner/img/jonar_logo_color.png');
    },
     'mouseout': function () {
       $logo.attr('src', 'http://www.jonar.com/portal/partner/img/jonar_logo_white.png');
    }
});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/yeqzp6kw/**

Answer (score 1):

To change the logo when the box is hovered, use the mouse events of the box and not the logo. It can be done like this:

```
$(".box1").on({
  "mouseover" : function() {
    $(this).find(".jlogo").attr("src", "jonar_logo_color.png");
  },
  "mouseout" : function() {
    $this("this").find(".jlogo").attr("src", "jonar_logo_white.png");
  }
});
```

The `$this("this").find(".jlogo")` finds any element with the class `jlogo` that is a descendant of the element that was hovered.

Alternativly, you might be able to accomplish this effect using only CSS (which in my opinion is preferable). Replace the image with an empty div with the same class, and then use this CSS:

```
.jlogo {
    width: 100px; /* Width of image */
    height: 100px; /* Height of image */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: src("jonar_logo_color.png");
}

/* When the box is hovered. */
.box1:hover .jlogo {
    background-image: src("jonar_logo_white.png");
}
```

In case the image you used was inline, you might want to add `display: inline;` to get the div to behave in the same way. Also, if you want to avoid having an extra div just for the image, you could use it as a background image for the figcaption instead, and use `padding-left` to avoid the text covering it.

I shortened the URL of the images for readability. You should avoid using absolute paths anyway, since a change of webadress would brake your code.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments you can easily just change the code to use a background image and not need to use JavaScript at all.

But if you want to stick with your html code you have, why trigger events? Just change the code to listen for the mouse events on the box element.

```
$(".box1").on({
 "mouseenter" : function() {
    $(this).find(".jlogo").attr("src", 'http://www.jonar.com/portal/partner/img/jonar_logo_color.png');
  },
  "mouseleave" : function() {
    $(this).find(".jlogo").attr("src",'http://www.jonar.com/portal/partner/img/jonar_logo_white.png');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As for me it will be more elegant to do only with CSS:

**HTML**

```
    <a href="http://support.jonar.com/support/default.asp?W2294">
     <div class="box1">
      <figure>
        <div class="jlogo"></div>
        <figcaption>
            Jonar &amp; You
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
     </div>
    </a>
```

**CSS**

```
 .box1:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(25, 16, 20), rgb(74, 41, 39));
    background: -o-linear-gradient(rgb(25, 16, 20), rgb(74, 41, 39));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(25, 16, 20), rgb(74, 41, 39));
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(25, 16, 20), rgb(74, 41, 39));
 }

 .box1 .jlogo{
    width:80px;
    height: 64px;
    background-image: url("http://www.jonar.com/portal/partner/img/jonar_logo_white.png");
 }

 .box1:hover .jlogo{
    background-image: url("http://www.jonar.com/portal/partner/img/jonar_logo_color.png");
 }
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/auj3Lyhr/)